# Problems running PyQt4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python3, pyqt

I programmed a small GUI in python and PyQt4 on Ubuntu 14.
When I try to run the same script on Ubuntu 18.04, I get an import error:

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'`

I have installed the following packages with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install pyqt4.qsci-dev
```

Short: all the packages that should enable PyQt4 to run on machine. I haven't found anyone with the same problem nor a site stating that PyQt4 won't run on Ubuntu 18.

Could it be that there is no possibility to run PyQt4 on Ubuntu 18? Or should I take PyQt5?

Sorry if this is the wrong forum, if you can't answer this question I'll post it on stack exchange.

My Python version is 3.6.5

Comment: See my answer below for solution. I am stupid. Anyways I'm going to move to PyQt5, as this is more recent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, found the error on my own.
I had to do the following:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt4
```

classic error, I installed the old python packages. Hint: apt-get is replaced by apt.

Comment: This solved my problem after many failed "solutions" from StackExchange. Thank you!